# Is "p not implies q" logically equivalent to "not p implies q"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am confused about whether $(A \not\rightarrow B)$ is logically equivalent to ~$(A \rightarrow B)$?

Comment: I have never seen "not implies" as a logical connective. Do you know its truth table?

Comment: I haven't seen it either, where did you get this question from?, maybe a textbook?

Comment: :( No I don't. I couldn't find any, that's why I got confused about whether "p not implies q" is equivalent to "not p implies q".

Comment: Usually if you have any binary boolean operator $a?b$, then $a\not?b$ means $\lnot(a?b)$.

Comment: The statement "$p$ does not imply $q$" certainly isn't the same as "not $p$ implies $q$."  Let $p$ be "I went to college"  and let $q$ be "I am a doctor".

Comment: Note:   $\sim(p\to q)$ is different from $(\sim p )\to q,$ and when written with words without parentheses as in the title it’s not clear what’s intended

Comment: @lulu perhaps some more parentheses would be useful there.  It almost looks like you are implying that you think what is being discussed is $\neg (p\implies q)$ being the same as $(\neg p)\implies q$.  Certainly having not gone to college will not imply that you are a doctor.  What seems is being asked is rather how to show that "it is possible to go to college and despite this not become a doctor."

Comment: @JMoravitz  Ah, I see your point.  Yes, I parsed "not $p$ implies $q$" incorrectly.

Comment: @lulu: The question is how to parse "not $p$ implies $q$": you parsed it as $(\neg p)\to q$, but it could be parsed as "\neg(p\to q)$".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Agreed.

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi: It looks like this could just be a case of awkward translation. Usually, we say "$p$ does not imply $q$", to mean precisely $\neg(p\to q)$. It could have been expressed (somewhat ungrammatical and non-standard) as "$p$ not implies $q$".

Answer (score 6):

I would generally consider $p\not\to q$ to be an *abbreviation for* $\neg(p\to q)$, so they are equivalent *by definition*!

Note, however, that $\neg(p\to q)$ is *not* the same as $(\neg p)\to q$, and if you write $\neg p\to q$ it generally means the latter of these.